# Mute functionality not working on SansungSmartTV

Tags: javascript, html, samsung-smart-tv

Mute functionality for my app is not working on the device(i.e., TV),But working on the emulator-2.5 and partially working on the emulator-3.5(Here partially means it silences the audio, but does not apply styles(i.e., BackgroundImage which resembles mute).

Importantly my app is rejected showing the reason '**mute doesn't silence the audio**'. But it is working in 2.5 emulator and partially working on Emulator-3.5.

How can I fix this error to publish my app?

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty strange - mute and volume+/- normally works. Which TVs models are you targeting? Are you handling the keys correctly (http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/tec00114/index.html)?

Comment: Really yaar,It behaving In-consistantly.It working partially in 3.5 emulator and completly working on 2.5 emulator.If it work on 2.5 emulator can it work on TV(device or not)

Comment: Emulators are buggy - I would not trust them, we are testing only on televisions.

Comment: i check it my TV its working fine.But samsung reject my app by showing "MUTE DOES'NT SILENCE THE AUDIO"

Comment: Ask for video attachment for the prove and better view how they do the reproduction step of your problem

Comment: I came to know that on 2013 TV mute functionality not working,But working on 2011 TV &Partially on 2012 TV also............                     So it behaving differently on different TV models,But my targetted model is 2013 TV

Answer (score 0):

Do you have correctly unregistered keys? http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/tec00147/index.html